# Xcode 4.2 / iOS 5 - Atleast one of the following architectures must be present : armv6

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, xcode4.2

I've just upgraded to iOS5 / Xcode 4.2 and I'm now trying to submit an application to the App Store. When I try to validate my Archive, I get an error saying:

> > iPhone / iPod touch : application executable is missing a required architecture. Atleast one of the following architectures must be present: armv6

I've checked a few similar questions and the most of the accepted answers just said set the `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO`. I've done this already and I still have the same issue. Here are my keys:

```
Architectures:

Distribution: Standard (armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

Base SDK : iOS 5.0

Build Active Architecture Only: NO

Valid Architectures: armv6 armv7
```

Any help on how to fix this is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Teja

EDIT: Also added key armv6 manually to the Architectures section in the Build Settings. No change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the Target to iOS 4.3 will get rid of the App Store error, as iOS 4.3 requires armv7 and is not supported on the older armv6 devices.

Comment: Ah, got it. But why exclude users that haven't updated their OSes ? I think I'd let it stay for now.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the armv6 key manually to the Architectures section of the Target that I was archiving.. not the whole project. This worked to get my submission to the AppStore done, but I'll hold out for a better answer.

Comment: This is indeed correct. I assume Apple wants us to willingly add the armv6 so that everyone else just moves on, creating more and more armv7-only apps.

Answer (score 1):

To continue to support the older architectures (e.g. iPhone 3G), just select your app target and select "Build Settings". At the top, change the Architectures listed from "Standard (armv7)" to "Other". In the pop-up box, select the existing option and click the minus button, then click the plus button and add "armv7", then again click plus and add "armv6". armv7 will support the newer chips, while armv6 will add back in support for the iPhone 3G... providing you set your iOS Deployment Target to iOS 4.2 or earlier... your setting at 3.x should be just fine—that merely limits you to not using newer features of iOS obviously.

You may also need to add "-mno-thumb" under "Other C Flags" in the Build Settings, though if my memory serves me correctly that may only have been if you are wanting to use Automatic Reference Counting on the old architecture—and even then only because this is a work-around for a known bug.